# Increased rate of bad plans (Oracle ACS)

Tags: oracle, execution-plan

In the last weeks I noticed an increased number of cases where Oracle starts to pick notoriously bad plans for some statements on widely different systems (Exadata, ODA and AIX).

I haven’t seen that much before with our applications, so I wonder if this is related to a recent patch (the systems seems to have different releases/Versions). Or maybe the default analyser settings have changed?

In one particular case a primary (unique) index is not used for a simple primary key lookup but instead it seems to use some kind of index fast scan. I thought adaptive coursor sharing is actually not used for that kind of simple query.

Comment: Have you checked to see if stats have been gathered recently? Could somebody have executed `DBMS_RESOURCE_MANAGER.CALIBRATE_IO()` by accident?

Comment: Yes the plan changes when/while the tables are analyzed, the stats are gathered always automatically this is not something new.

Comment: Is the calibrate_io somewhere visible in awr data history?